# Where to place the user certs hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Enrolling a identity creates certificate files. Where should these certs go in a fabric network

`$fabric-ca-client enroll --id.name user1 --id.type user --id. affiliation org1 -M ./user1cert/msp`

client certificates are stored in signcerts folder. As i understand the certs in this folder is the certificate for the particular user.

Should we send this certificate to user or place it somewhere inside the network(in peer, cli, orderer)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The user's public certs are mounted in the components of HF network where required. The private certs are sent to the user (certs in keystore folder). To authenticate with the network, users will use apps created by using SDKs.

In fabcar example, the private certs are placed inside hfc-keystore folder.

Hence the private certs are sent to users, which are then used by apps (SDK generated apps) to authenticate the them.